# How can I install more partitions, I have two I think swap and primary I guess?

Tags: 13.04, gnome, partitioning, swap

My friend was on skype explaining to me how to install linux so we didn't take whole hard disk space for linux. He said that later I can always edit that and add partitions, I don't even now how to check how much space swap area is allotted to me, I read here it says it should be 4gb I think that we set it to more, I am new to linux, so I am asking for help here, my hard disk is 640 bytes and later I think in few months I will surely install windows 7 because linux looks too complicated to me, but I want to try to take whole hard disk space for linux to use gim for few months maybe I will learn how to use it and everything will be ok. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Software Center and look for *GParted*. Install and open the program (with root permission) and then you can edit, create and delete partitios.
As a note: Always be careful when changing existing partitions. This can lead into loss of data.

PS: After installing Windows 7, boot your Live Ubuntu (DVD or Stick or whatever you used) and set the `boot` flag back to the ubuntu partition, so GRUB is used as bootloader again. Afterwards open a terminal and type `sudo update-grub`. This will refresh GRUB and add Windows 7 to GRUB's OS list. Windows bootloaders can't recognise EXT partitions and therefore can't boot Ubuntu, which is on EXT4 (?) by default.

Comment: OK i did that thanks now one more question when i create new one,new partition what should i set in fields like ext3,ext4 something like that and should i set it like another primary and what should i set at mount point

Comment: Don't set a mount point, the partitiorn type depends on what you want to do with it. IF you want the partition to be usable, use `ntfs`, else use `ext4`. If it should be a swap partition, use `swap`.